# How to “downcast” an array of [NSManageObject] to the selected entity?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I am developing an App using CoreData.

I have 5 entities (A, B, C, D, E) and 90% of the attributes of each entity are common. 10% are different.

I created an array of [NSManageObject] to store the fetchRequest of the selected entity. Until that point everything seems to work.

Here is my fetchRequest code. First of all I made an extension of NSManagedObjectContext:

```
extension NSManagedObjectContext {

func fetchMOs (_ entityName: String, sortBy: [NSSortDescriptor]? = nil, predicate: NSPredicate? = nil) throws -> [NSManagedObject] {

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)

    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    request.predicate = predicate
    request.sortDescriptors = sortBy

    return try! self.fetch(request) as! [NSManagedObject]

    }
}
```

Then I request the data by calling to this function within the context:

```
documentArray = try! context.fetchMOs(requestedEntity!, sortBy: requestedSortBy, predicate: requestedPredicate)
```

The problem comes when I want to access the attributes of the selected entity to work with them.

For example, I selected entity A and the fetchRequest stored the data in the array [NSManageObject]. Now I want to print one attribute of the entity:
[NSManageObject].attribute1 <— but this is incorrect.
It should be: [A].attribute1

I guess I could do a switch statement to downcast and work with the data:

```
Switch entitySelected {
   Case “A”:
      arrayOfMO as! [A]
      arrayOfMO.attribute1 ......
```

And so on for each entity. But it seems to me that there should be a more clean way of doing that.

The data stored in the entities are Strings and what I want to do with it is just to fill labels and buttons in a tableViewController.

Thanks.

Comment: Do share your fetchRequest. What is entitySelected?

Comment: Option 1: Define a common parent entity. Option 2: Define a common protocol.

Comment: Maybe take a look at my answer to your previous question, it depends on what you mean to do with your entities

Comment: @Carpsen90 I edited the post with the information you asked. entitySelected is a String that receives a value in the performSegue, depending on which button you pushed in the home screen.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I edited the post to write what I want to do with the data from the entities. It is just to fill labels and buttons in a tableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Try next:

```
    extension NSManagedObjectContext {
        func fetchMOs<T: NSManagedObject>(sortBy: [NSSortDescriptor]? = nil, predicate: NSPredicate? = nil) throws -> [T] {

            let request = NSFetchRequest<T>(entity: T.entity())

            request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
            request.predicate = predicate
            request.sortDescriptors = sortBy

            return try? self.fetch(request) ?? []
        }
    }
```

Then you can get

```
    let results: [SomeMoClass] = moc.fetchMOs<SomeMoClass>()
```